# Sort Two column and create new columns for sorted values from dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataframe. I want to sort column `'X'` from dataframe d1 and keep the order `Y` as per `X` values.
and then create a new dataframe called `df2` where sorting is done but original dataframe should remain as it is.

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'X':[4,3,5,6], 'Y':[0.5,0.7,0.2,0.9]}
df= pd.DataFrame(d1)
```

Original Dataframe

```
   X    Y
0  4  0.5
1  3  0.7
2  5  0.2
3  6  0.9
```

Expected DataFrame

```
   X    Y  X_Sorted  Y_Sorted
0  4  0.5         6       0.9
1  3  0.7         5       0.2
2  5  0.2         4       0.5
3  6  0.9         3       0.7
```

Here `Y_Sorted` as per index of `X` values.

`Y` values will remain same as per `x_sorted` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html), create default index and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df1 = (df[['X','Y']].sort_values('X', ascending=False)
                    .add_suffix('_sorted')
                    .reset_index(drop=True))
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
print (df)
   X    Y  X_sorted  Y_sorted
0  1  0.5         6       0.9
1  3  0.7         5       0.2
2  5  0.2         3       0.7
3  6  0.9         1       0.5
```

Comment: If I have more column then '_sorted' will get apply on all columns.I just need to apply on X and Y.... In my original dataframe i have more columns.

Comment: @Maddy6 - Add `[['X','Y']]` for filter only columns for add suffix

Comment: i didn't understand where exactly to add. Can you write.

Comment: @Maddy6 - change `df` to `df[['X','Y']]`